# Secure network storage of settings

Tags: security, service, settings

I have a corporate network with several services, each of which stores some settings (including connection strings, logins and passwords). I want to use one common service (or application with API) to securely store all settings in one place.
Are there any ready solutions (open source or paid) for this?

Comment: What are the OS of the servers and the scenario you're protecting against? Someone reading the files directly, someone connecting to the network and pretends to be one of the approved servers, etc?

Comment: Basically used Windows, but the platform does not matter, it can be Linux